# How to add a custom shape based on the properties of the two selected shapes (VBA, PowerPoint)?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

A user would mark two shapes and when I run the macro I'm looking to add a shape in between the two selected shapes.

The new shape would line up with the 2 inner corners of the shape. How could I achieve this?

Here's an example (blue = the new shape; black = the selected user shapes):
[image]

Comment: This looks like what you would need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.buildfreeform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim sa As Shape, sb As Shape, sld As Slide
    Dim ff As FreeformBuilder, points, newShp As Shape
    
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) 'for example
    Set sa = sld.Shapes(1)
    Set sb = sld.Shapes(2)
    
    points = Array(sa.Left + sa.Width, sa.Top, _
                   sb.Left, sb.Top, _
                   sb.Left, sb.Top + sb.Height, _
                   sa.Left + sa.Width, sa.Top + sa.Height)

    Set newShp = CreateClosedPolygon(sld, points)
    
    newShp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow 'do something with the returned shape
    
End Sub

'Create and return a new closed polygon shape on slide `sld`, using an array
'  of n pairs of Left+Top values (each pair being a point)
Function CreateClosedPolygon(sld As Slide, points) As Shape
    Dim i As Long, lb As Long, ub As Long, ff As FreeformBuilder
    lb = LBound(points)
    ub = UBound(points)
    'first point
    Set ff = sld.Shapes.BuildFreeform(EditingType:=msoEditingCorner, _
                                     x1:=points(lb), y1:=points(lb + 1))
    'other points
    For i = lb + 2 To ub Step 2
        ff.AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingCorner, points(i), points(i + 1)
    Next i
    'close the shape back to the first point
    ff.AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingCorner, points(lb), points(lb + 1)
    Set CreateClosedPolygon = ff.ConvertToShape() 'create and return the final shape
End Function
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

You would need to add the code to determine which 2 shapes are selected and figure out which one is on the left and which one is on the right.